# Validate user and redirect to login or home in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario in which I want to validate user on page load.
I want same script for all pages including Login and Home pages, in which if user is logged In redirect to Home else redirect to login. 
In my code it fails due to too many redirects. need simple solution for that.
here is my code:

session.php

```
<?php
   define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
   define('DB_USERNAME', '');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_DATABASE', 'auth');
   $db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

   session_start();

   $checkId = ''; $checkUser = ''; $checkPass = '';

   if(isset($_SESSION['login_userId'])){ $checkId = $_SESSION['login_userId']; };
   if(isset($_SESSION['login_userName'])){ $checkUser = $_SESSION['login_userName']; };
   if(isset($_SESSION['login_userPass'])){ $checkPass = $_SESSION['login_userPass']; };

   $sessionResult = mysqli_query($db, "select * from users where id='$checkId' AND username='$checkUser' AND password='$checkPass'");
   $getSessionRow = mysqli_fetch_array($sessionResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $sessionRowcount = mysqli_num_rows($sessionResult);

   if(isset($getSessionRow['username']) && $checkUser == $getSessionRow['username']){
      header("location:home.php");
   }
   else {
      header("location:login.php");
   }
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Login</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Login page with login Form</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

home.php

```
<?php
include('session.php');
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Welcome</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Welcome to Home page</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean with too many redirects but you should `exit()` after using `header(...)` - Edit: _login.php & home.php pages..._ It shouldn'tbe like that!

Comment: I have used same file `session.php` on login page, it start looping and redirecting again and again.

Comment: You should separate both scripts

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: That's not my focus right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using same session page in both pages of course it will redirect to much. You have to delete session php from login and home. In login create a form after button click post it to session php so it can redirect. In home php on top create an if statement check if session login is logged in else send it to session php that will stop all loops.

Comment: I have achieved by making separate session files for login and home pages but that is not my target... my question is, How I can use same `session.php` file for both pages?

Comment: As i said before, in session.php inside user control create a session like user logged in true after than that in home.php create a if statement if(!isset(SESSION[“userlogedin”])){header(session.php)} thats it 1 session file and you have to use this if statement every file except  login , register and logout in that files you have to destroy session

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing after run session page set login id in session and at the start of home page check if not exist (isset) login id then redirect it to login same for login page.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
{
    header("location:login.php");
}
```